# Why does my code mess up with i++ and numsWon++ when the '++' operators are after?

Tags: c++, operators

I struggled with problem 1535 (Find the Winner of an Array Game) on LeetCode. I decided to use the top solution, which looked like this:

```
int getWinner(vector<int>& A, int k) {
    int cur = A[0], win = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        if (A[i] > cur) {
            cur = A[i];
            win = 0;
        }
        if (++win == k) break;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

However, I implemented it like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int getWinner(vector<int>& arr, int k) {
        int win = arr[0];
        int numsWon = 0;
        
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if(arr[i] > win) {
                numsWon = 0;
                win = arr[i];
            }
            
            if(numsWon++ == k) break;
        }
        return win;
    }
};
```

The code didn't work until I switched the `++` operators. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Google 'c++ pre increment vs post increment'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Comment: Is it surprising that code stops working when you change it? If nothing else, this should tell you that `++win` and `win++` mean different things. They are similar, but in coding, changing one seemingly minor detail can break an entire system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for:

```
if (++win == k) break;
```

The value of win is incremented by 1 first, and then is put though the comparison operator. It is the same as doing.

```
win = win + 1;  
if(win == k) break;
```

where as when the ++ is after the win, it increments the value of win after the comparison like:

```
if(win == k){  
    win = win + 1;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`++x` happens prior to assignment (pre-increment), but `x++` happens after assignment (post-increment). `x++` executes the statement and then increments the value. `++x` increments the value and then executes the statement.

Read about post and pre increment in c++.

[Post and Pre increment gfg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-c/)

[What is the difference between pre-increment and post-increment in the cycle (for/while)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366847/what-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-the-cycle-fo)