# What do the comparison operators in the body of a for loop do?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, comparison-operators

I've entered my programming class' exam where i've encountered a question in which i was asked to interpret what would the result of the code block written in C would be and the code block is as follows...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int x = 1, y = 1;

   for (; y; printf("%d %d |", x, 
   y))
        y = x++ <= 5;

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

What struck me ass odd is that a comparison operator (=<) is put inside the body of the for loop instead of the condition-test part of the for loop.
Could you explain what it does?
I tried to be as descriptive as i can, hope you understood well.

Comment: Two answers. (1) This code causes your code review to fail, because your coworkers don't want to deal with tricky stuff like this. (2) Ask your professor after the exam.

Comment: Comparisons are considered arithmetic operators, similar to `+` or `*`. And like any other arithmetic expression, comparisons give a result. It should not be hard to figure out the result of a comparison.

Comment: Also worth noting that this doesn't compile. https://godbolt.org/z/W1a4oMMqq

Comment: Please clarify: since this is an exam question, are you asking for help in cheating on it?  Be aware that your professor is entirely capable of finding this question on this site and noticing that it matches their exam question, then catching you when your answer looks similar to a posted answer.  And if you were thinking of deleting the question after you get an answer, it won't work - moderators will undelete it.  (Or your professor may have 10K rep which allows them to view deleted posts.)

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect, `=<` is the problem. Either you mistyped it and then correct it, or it has been given exactly like this and then has no meaning.

Comment: Yeah i mistyped that, it was supposed to be (<=).

Comment: I also posted this question after the exam was over so it's not a problem

Comment: @therealramos Update code to reflect the correct `<=`.  Also review `printf("/n");`.  was that `"\n"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `for`-loop has the form

```
  for(<init>; <condition>; <iteration>) {<body>}
```

which is exactly equivalent to the following (except that all occurrences of outer-loop `continue` in the `<body>` must be substituted with `<iteration>; continue`):

```
  {
     <init>;
     while(<condition>) {
       <body>
       <iteration>
     }
  }
```

Hence, the `for`-loop in the OP code (with obvious corrections) can be written as:

```
   {
     while(y) {
        y = x++ <= 5;
        printf("%d %d |", x, y));
     }
   }
```

The expression `y = x++ <= 5;` assigns to `y` the result of the boolean expression `x++ <= 5`. There is nothing "magic" about this. It will assign `1` to `y` if and only if `x <= 5` and then increment `x` by one. The value of `y` (0 or 1) will then be the condition for executing the next iteration of the loop.

Thus, the loop will run for `x` (initially in the body) being 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. When `x` is 6, `y` will become 0 and the `printf`-statement will be run a final time with `x` having the incremented value, 7.

The result of this code is simple, but it is unnecessarily difficult to understand. A better version could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   for(int x = 2; x <= 7; x++) {
     int y = (x == 7) ? 0 : 1;
     printf("%d %d |", x, y));
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those are not equivalent because a `continue;` in the body skips an `<iteration>` included in the body but not one in the `for` statement proper.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That ternary operator you just put in the body of the loop made more sense.

Comment: One more thing caught my attention, what would the output of this program be if x++ was replaced with ++x? I'd really appreciate if you answer.

Comment: @therealramos "what would the output of this program be if x++ was replaced with ++x?" --> certainly you can code that yourself to determine the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As always you have a keen eye on the details and you are of course right. I have tried to update the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @therealramos Using `x++` or `++x` only makes a difference if the value is used within the given expression. In this case (unlike the OP code), `x++` is an expression by itself and the value of `x++` is not used within that expression so using `++x` or `x++` does not make any difference to the result (and most likely not to the generated code either). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366847/what-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-the-cycle-fo) (C++, but it largely applies to C as well).