# C++ Commas inside the for loop and its equivalent expression?

Tags: for-loop

So I was wondering what the equivalent expression for this for loop would be I honestly have never seen for loop written this way due to lack of experience I guess.

Here is the code:

```
    string convertToBase7(int num) {
     int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; num!=0; res += pow(10,i++)*(num % 7), num /= 7) {}
    return to_string(res);
}
```

so does the statments after the semi-colon get executed at each iteration in the order it is written? Also at say at i = 2  then, res += pow(10,3)? Is that correct?

Comment: That code is terrible and you should not seek to emulate it.

Comment: How a `for` loop works (and `i++` for that matter) should be covered in any basic text book.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5 && j < 3; ++i, ++j)
```

is similar to:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < 5 && j < 3) {
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
```

> so does the statments after the semi-colon get executed at each iteration in the order it is written?

As you can see from above code *yes*.

> Also at say at i = 2 then, res += pow(10,3)? Is that correct?

Not necessarily because it is not guarantied that `i` would be incremented before it was passed to a function. Check this out:
[Order of operations for pre-increment and post-increment in a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989704/order-of-operations-for-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-function-argument?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You have also this problem

```
num != 0;
```

what would happen if division:

```
num /= 7;
```

skips zero, by accident, thus I recommend you do following:

```
num > 0;
```

So with all of the above, I would write this line:

```
for(int i=0; num!=0; res += pow(10,i++)*(num % 7), num /= 7) {}
```

as follows:

```
 for(int i=0; num!=0; ++i, res += pow(10,i)*(num % 7), num /= 7) {}
```

if I need to make sure `i` is incremented before it is passed to a function, or.:

```
for(int i=0; num!=0; res += pow(10,i)*(num % 7), ++i, num /= 7) {}
```

If I need to make sure `i` is incremented after it is passed to a funciton.