# What is order of evaluation in printf() for pointer

Tags: c, pointers, printf, pointer-arithmetic

`

```
a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, ++*ptr);
```

`

The output is - 11 11

How is it evaluated??

Comment: @EugeneSh. there's no sequence point between them, so UB

Comment: @PaulHankin OK, right. Was under wrong impression that evaluation of each parameter is sequenced as a full expression

Comment: The order of evaluation is not specified. That is the problem. Imo sequence point is there.

Comment: @0___________ The sequence point is when entering the function, but there isn't between evaluation of the two parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour, so the result could be anything. There is no sequence point in the line, which means that both operations are unsequenced - either argument could be evaluated first, or both simultaneously (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point and John Bollinger's comment).

For example, when evaluating with the clang compiler, this is the output:

```
<source>:5:26: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
    printf("%d %d\n", a, ++a);
                      ~  ^
1 warning generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
2 3
```

See this answer for more: [Order of operations for pre-increment and post-increment in a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989704/order-of-operations-for-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-function-argument)

Comment: The "For example, if `a` is evaluated first" is nonsensical and obscures the point.  The inherent issue is that `a` is *not* evaluated before `++*ptr`, nor after, nor even at the same time.  The evaluations of those two expressions are *unsequenced* relative to each other as far as C semantics are concerned.  And because they are unsequenced and one has a side effect on an object read by the other, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have removed it and tried to improve the answer